# Search custom fields (meta data) in Wordpress via actions/filters

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

How can I modify the Wordpress search so that it also searches for meta data (custom fields)?

I'd like to do that via the `WP_Query` Object, but i am a little lost, since I don't know which filter/action to use. I have to do it via filters or actions because I am not allowed to change core or template files. I tried to understand how it's done in 'Relevanssi', but it's a lot of code to analyze for it is so powerful. I just need a bit of its functionality.

I tried the following actions/filters:
`pre_get_posts`,
`the_posts`,
`posts_request`,
`query_vars` and
`posts_search`.

I had some success using the `posts_search` filter where you can specify raw SQL commands, but table and field names may change in the future and I wanted to use `WP_query` as an abstract layer. All in all, `WP_Query` represents a SQL query in the end, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search-everything/). It's a nice plugin and can search in meta data as well. If you don't want to install it than look into the logic of search and implement with your idea.